# sqlalchemy's create_all doesn't create sequences automatically

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy 0.4.8 with Postgres in order to manage my datastore. Until now, it's been fairly easy to automatically deploy my database: I was using `metadata.create_all(bind=engine)` and everything worked just fine. But now I am trying to create a sequence that it's not being used by any table, so `create_all()` doesn't create it, even though it's define correctly:
`Sequence('my_seq', metadata=myMetadata)`.

Any thoughts on how I could make this work ?

**P.S.** And it's not possible at the moment to upgrade to a newer version of SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Have you tried "using" that sequence in an otherwise-unused table, just as a workaround?

Comment: No, but it's a good idea. What I am trying to achieve it's actually more hackish than that: I am trying to keep an id between different runs of a script - so instead of storing it in a file, I was thinking that having a db sequence it's more clear. Thanks, Alex!

Answer (score 6):

Could you call the `create` it by using its own [Sequence.create](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/reference/sqlalchemy/schema.html?highlight=sequence#sqlalchemy.schema.Sequence.create) method:

```
my_seq = Sequence('my_seq', metadata=myMetadata)
# ...
metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
# @note: create unused objects explicitly
my_seq.create(bind=engine)
# ...
```